# Solving an SDE with time-dependent parameter in R

Tags: differential-equations, r, julia, stochastic-ode

I am trying to solve a system of SDEs in `R` using the `Diffeqr package`.

Let's reduce the system to a simple ODE:

```
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(diffeqr)
library(JuliaCall)
diffeq_setup()

# Drift function
f <- function(u,p,t){
  du1 = p[1]  
  return(c(du1))
}

# Diffusion function
g <- function(u,p,t){
  du1 = 0 # note that there is currenlty no noise
}

u0 = 1                   
tspan <- list(0.0, 100)       
p = 1
sol = sde.solve(f, g, u0, seed = 1, tspan, p=p, saveat=0.05)
udf=as.data.frame(sol$u)
udf <- udf %>% rownames_to_column(var = "time") 
udf <- udf %>% rename(y=`sol$u`)
plot(udf$time, udf$y, type = "l", xlim = c(0,400))
```

I was wondering if it is possible to alter the parameters time-dependently? I tried to replace `p=1` with `p=c( c(1,2,3,4,5) )` (as an example), but that doesn't work.

Or are there other solutions to solve systems of SDEs with time-dependent parameters in R?

Comment: If you pass a function as the parameter, you should be able to call it as `p(t)`.

Comment: Hehe it works! I was thinking it would work. The fact that it works wasn't directly coded into the package, but it's really the result of JuliaCall being awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter can be any type, so here I pass in a time-dependent function for `p` and use it in the differential equation:

```
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(diffeqr)
library(JuliaCall)
diffeq_setup()

# Drift function
f <- function(u,p,t){
  du1 = p(t)
  return(c(du1))
}

# Diffusion function
g <- function(u,p,t){
  du1 = 0 # note that there is currenlty no noise
}

u0 = 1                   
tspan <- list(0.0, 100)       
p <- function(t){
  t
}
sol = sde.solve(f, g, u0, tspan, p=p, saveat=0.05)
udf=as.data.frame(sol$u)
udf <- udf %>% rownames_to_column(var = "time") 
udf <- udf %>% rename(y=`sol$u`)
plot(udf$time, udf$y, type = "l", xlim = c(0,400))
```

Comment: Nice! I guess it will also work to add the function itself inside a vector of some independent variables and a time-dependent variable? Or multiple time-dependent variables in different functions? Or would you, in that case, need one function that returns the complete parameter vector?

Comment: I think a vector of functions (or other things) should just work.